# Is this main method defined correctly?

Tags: scala

In below class is my main method not defined correctly ? When I try to run it from Eclipse I dont have the option to run it as a scala program. When I remove `filesEnding(".txt")` I can then run the program.

```
object FileMatcher {

  private def filesHere = (new java.io.File(".")).listFiles()

  private def filesMatching(matcher: String => Boolean) = 
    for(file <- filesHere; if matcher(file.getName))
        yield file

  def filesEnding(query: String) = filesMatching(_.endsWith(query))

  def main(args:Array[String]) = {
      filesEnding(".txt")
  }

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Main must return type `Unit`.  But `filesEnding` does not return `Unit`, it returns files.  The easiest fix is to remove the `=` so the return value from the method defaults to `Unit`.

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
// ...
}
```